# How to read all values corresponding to a nested Key in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am a newbie to MongoDB. Probably this question is asked earlier, but I am not getting the solution as desired, by trying the answers given to similar questions

I want to import the value corresponding to "_data.review_Message" into a Python Panda dataframe from the a mongoDB documents (with JSON Structure) as given below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e24b225c0f4439356814ee"),
    "_source" : "example.com",
    "_title" : "jspringertx",
    "_url" : "http://www.example.com/ShowUserReviews-g56014-d140093-r134096684-",
    "_data" : {
    "PO Box 508, Huntsville, TX 77342 " : {
            "reviewer_MemberSince" : "Travelling with us since 2011",
            "reviewer_NumberOfContributions" : "119",
            "reviewer_HelpfulVotes" : "23",
            "reviewThingsToDo_PhoneNumber" : "409-295-5644",
            "review_Title" : "Huntsville State Park",
            "reviewer_Name" : "jspringertx",
            "reviewer_NumberOfCitiesVisited" : "81",
            "review_Message" : "Be prepared to have a picnic lunch or hike thru the ..",
            "review_DatePosted" : "Reviewed July 11, 2012",
            "reviewer_NumberOfReviewedCities" : "10",
            "reviewer_NumberOfAttractionReviews" : "21",
            "reviewThingsToDo_Address" : "PO Box 508, Huntsville, TX 77342 ",
            "reviewer_NumberOfReviews" : "54",
            "review_RatingLevel" : "3 of 5 stars",
            "reviewer_CityOfResidence" : "Houston, Texas\n65+ year old man"
            }
     },
    "_attemp_time" : 1407339298.555776
}
```

I have tried using the Mongo Query:

```
sandbox.example_Reviews_Texas.find({}, { "_id":0, "_data.review_Message" : 1 })
```

where the db name is sandbox and the collection name is example_Reviews_Texas. I am getting null values. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your quoted structure, the path to review_Message is:

```
"_data.PO Box 508, Huntsville, TX 77342 .review_Message" // note the space after 77342.
```

So you will get the result, if you query as below:

```
sandbox.example_Reviews_Texas.find({}, { "_id":0, "_data.PO Box 508, Huntsville, TX 77342 .review_Message" : 1 })
```

**Note:** The above will help you only retrieve at least one document.